# ASP.NET MVC Overriding Index action with optional parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-4.5.2

I want to accept `/User/` and `/User/213123`

Where *213123* is a parameter (user_id)

Here is my *RouteConfig.cs*:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "user",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{username}",
                defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And my *UserController.cs*:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "user index";
            return View();
        }

        [Route("user/{username}")]
        public ActionResult Index(string username)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "!" + username + "!";
            return View();
        }
```

This works in .net-core 1.0 but not in mvc5. What am I missing?

Thank you

EDIT:

Having just this in my UserController.cs also doesn't work (returns 404):

```
        public ActionResult Index(string username)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Hello " + username;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "user index";
            }

            return View();
        }
```

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /user/asd

EDIT2:

Updated *RouteConfig.cs*:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "userParam", "user/{username}",
          new { controller = "user", action = "IndexByUsername" },
          new { username = @"\w+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "user",
            url: "user",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index"}
        );
```

`/User/` now calls `IndexByUsername` with *Index* as the username

`/User/asd` still returns 404

**EDIT4**: Current code:

*RouteConfig.cs:*

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
routes.MapRoute("userParam", "user/{username}", new { controller = "user", action = "Index"});
routes.MapRoute("user", "{controller}/{action}/{username}", new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

*UserController.cs*:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Hello " + username;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "user index";
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need `public ActionResult Index(string username)` (and check if `username` is `null` or not)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please see my edit

Comment: Your url is `/user/asd` which tries to call the `asd()` method of `userController` - which does not exist hence the 404. It would need to be `user/index/asd` (or you can create a specific route for just `/user/{username}`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please see my latest edit.

Comment: You must have to create a specific route for your action. As said by @StephenMuecke, /user/abcd will always look for abcd action under user controller until you make specific route for that.

Comment: `"user/{username}"` would need to be `new { controller = "user", action = "Index" }`, (not `action = IndexByUsername`). And for the second one, you just need the original route definition you had, or alternatively you could add `username = UrlParameter.Optional` to the `userParam` route and delete the `user` route

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm sorry to test your patience but I must be missing something, because I can't get this to work: `routes.MapRoute("userParam", "user/{username}",  new { controller = "user", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional });`

I still get a 404 when adding the username to the url

Comment: That should work fine. Are sure you routes are in the correct order (i.e this one is the first)

Comment: I have just copied your code from Edit 3 into a new project and it works fine - `/user/asd` hits the controller and the value of `username` is `"asd"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I figured it out why it's not working. I don't know how to fix it though and I feel stupid. See my last edit (edit4). I had another route in *RouteConfig.cs* but I never expected it would be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117312/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-cornwell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only one action method with the signature

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
```

and in that method you can check if the value of `username` is `null` or not.

Then you route definitiosn needs to be (note the `user` route needs to be placed before the default route)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "user",
    url: "user/{username}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```