# .net MVC Action with Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want that controller will accept /Details/1 and /User/xxx but not /User/

and i try it like below=>

```
    public ActionResult Details( Nullable<int> id, Nullable<string> name)
    {
        if (((id ?? 0) == 0) && name == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Instructor instructor = db.Instructors.Where(x => x.InstructorId == id || x.faculty_name.Equals(name)).SingleOrDefault();

        if (instructor == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
        return View(instructor);
    }
```

i want that(mansion above) user can pass /Details/1 or /Details/xxx but not /Details/ thats why i add condition check=>

```
        if (((id ?? 0) == 0) && name == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

but i wants to run the code the compiler gives me error something like=>
[image]
i was thinking that was perfect but i dont know why a have done wrong = i tried=>

```
    public ActionResult Details( int? id, string? name)
    {
    }
```

that was also gives me the same error.i searched about this problem and i found=>
[ASP.NET MVC Overriding Index action with optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370848/asp-net-mvc-overriding-index-action-with-optional-parameter)

i am not understanding anything . thats why i reposed this kind of problems.
this will be great full if anybody can help me?

Comment: `string` is already nullable. But you cannot have 2 nullable values as parameters and use routes (you will only be able to generate `/Details?name=xxx` - if you were to use `/Details/xxx` both parameters will be `null` and your code will always return `BadRequest`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke public ActionResult Details( int id = 0, string name = null) is return me a bad request....is there any way to solve this problem or i need to follow other structure

Comment: Just have one parameter (`string`) and then check if it can be parsed to `int`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i can understand can you just give me one little example?

Comment: Give me 20 min and I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is already nullable so `Nullable<string>` and `string?` make no sense. However you cannot have 2 nullable parameters and achieve the routes you want. The routing engine has no way of knowing which of the parameters should be bound, and if you were to use `../Details/xxx` both values would be `null` and you would always be returning `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest`.

You could achieve this using 2 separate methods (say `DetailsByID` and `DetailsByName`) and route definitions, but if you want a single method, then you can only have one parameter to account for all 3 routes. In the method you can then attempt to parse the value to `int`

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    int number;
    Instructor instructor;
    bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(id, out number);
    if (IsInt)
    {
        instructor = db.Instructors.Where(x => x.InstructorId == number).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        instructor = db.Instructors.Where(x => x.faculty_name.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    if (instructor == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.faculty_active = MyCustomFunctions.UserActivity();
    return View(instructor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Nullable<string>` because you do not needed and makes no sense.

`string` already accepts `null` value and that means is already `nullable`.

Short example:

```
string myString=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Nullable for Value Types, like int,demical,DateTime etc,.

String is a reference type so it allows null by default